# Socket.io connection URL for production

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, heroku, socket.io-1.0

When in development env, this works as expected,
Server Code... In development, I only specify the url in the client as const socket = io("http://localhost:3001"); Below is the server code.

```
const httpServer = createServer(app);
export const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
  path: "/socket.io/",
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // make function calls
  postOrderDeliveryStatus(socket);
  // getOrders(socket);
  // console.log("Socket Connected");

  // close socket
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    socket.disconnect(true);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3001);

//mongoose
// console.log(process.env.CONNECTION_URL)
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () =>
      winston.info(
        `Server Running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on Port: ${PORT}`
      )
    )
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

Client...

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001");
  
  const dispatchOrderHandler = () => {
    const delivery_status = "DISPATCHED";
    socket.emit("update-order", order._id, delivery_status);
    // dispatch(getOrderDetailsToProcess(paramsOrderId)); //This dispatch  alone can suffice
    socket.on("updated-order", (updated_order) => {
      dispatch(
        getOrderDetailsToProcess(paramsOrderId, (order) => [
          ...order,
          updated_order,
        ])
      );
    });
  };
```

The error i get when sockets run is net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I also tried
const socket = io(); without specifying the url since both the client and the server run on the same domain but that didn't either? What should the connection URL be in production since specifying the domain name hasn't worked? Am using heroku!

Answer (score 1):

When using a hosting service, the service will provide the port to the client. You can access that port through `process.env.PORT`. To make the experience a bit more friendly to yourself as a developer, you can listen to the port using `httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);`

As for the client, I believe you are right on using `const socket = io();`, although I haven't used socket.io in a while.

Comment: Thank you Kachow. What you suggested is actually how it's running locally. I also get the port defined automatically once in production by the hosting service . But note that I have app.listen serving the server and httpServer.listen serving the socket connection. So it's like I have to ports to be served from the server at the same time.

Comment: Using  const socket = io() didn't work. How can i point the socket in the client to the socket endpoint with the port defined in production?

Answer (score 0):

Use `const socket = io("serverurl")` to connect to a specific server.

I believe you can specify a port there as well.

So like for my website, I would do: `const socket = io("us2.swordbattle.io:3000")`

Comment: And what is the socket configuration on the server side @Gautam?

Comment: `const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: "*" }});`

Comment: This is currently mine in production @Mydhe

Comment: This is very helpful. However, my challenge is; initially the server was running on port 8000 then I introduced socket.io's logic in the server.js file. So how do I listen to two different ports (8000 and 3001) from the same server? What would the proxy configuration look like in client's package.json? Will it have the socket's url or the server's? @Coder Gautam Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm using heroku too, and for the server, do `httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001)`, like suggested by @Kachow095. Then, you should be able to connect with `const socket = io()` or `const socket = io("your-heroku-url")` without a port. Make sure you're on https).

Comment: If that doens't work, let me know

Comment: I struggled to find the combination that works for me in production because locally, all was working fine. I ended up switching to SSE. I think sockets were an overkill for my use case. Thanks for the efforts. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

const socket = io(); This works if your frontend is on the same domain as your server